# Getting custom subdomain after GitLab CI/CD

Tags: docker, gitlab, devops, cicd, self-hosting

coming here with a problem.

At the moment, I have a self hosted GitLab instance with Container Registry on server A. On server B, I have some GitLab runners that I have registered and I would like to be able to deploy my web apps for review as part of a CI/CD pipeline and be able to access the deployed apps in the browser.

For the time being, I have it hosted at git.domain.my and I would like to be able to deploy apps with/without docker/kubernetes and obtain a link to view in browser, something like

http://project-name-branch-name.git.domain.my.

I would really appreciate any tips or routes to follow for solving the issue.

For the moment, we tried setting up some Nginx based-deployments, but we have problems with setting up DNS with responding to URLs of type  http://project-name-branch-name.git.domain.my. on an automated basis after deployment.

Comment: `we have problems with setting up DNS with responding to URL` Well, you have to overcome those problems ans set it up. Your question is too broad - it's not specific. What "problems"? Yes, you have to setup your own DNS with autoregistration and your own http proxy with autoregistration. You can use nomad or kubernetes or docker + consul or dnsmasq + traefik or fabio or nginx or haproxy or anything other. Bottom line, yes, you have to set it up. I use nomad+docker+consul+fabio , but I'm nowhere to recommend it. But this forum is also not for software recommendations. Consider posting on reddit

Comment: Who is your DNS provider? If you use a service like Cloudflare, which is free to use, they have an API you could use to create DNS entries on the fly. 

I'm guessing that is only half the issue, the other half is setting up your Nginx webserver with "virtual hosts" so the one Nginx server can respond to multiple domains. If you search the Internet for "How to set up virtual hosts with nginx" you will get multiple answers on how to do that. It is really easy to do.